# Neo4j Path sampling

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, path-finding, knowledge-graph

I have `CALL apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(A, B, '', 3)` result that look like this:

- [A –>relation1 –>B]
- [A –>relation2 –>B]
- [A –>relation2->C->relation 1–>B]
- [A –>relation5->D->relation 3–>B]
- [A –>relation2->Y->relation 1–>B]
- [A –>relation2->E->relation 1–>B]
- [A –>relation2->D–>relation2->F->relation 1–>B]
- [A –>relation2->F–>relation4->Y->relation 2–>B]

**Desired result:** FOREACH pathlength, randomly return 1 row

- [A –>relation2 –>B]
- [A –>relation2->Y->relation 1–>B]
- [A –>relation2->D–>relation2->F->relation 1–>B]

The result is representative of all pathlengths:

The first row:

[A –>relation2 –>B]     is a sample from path length 1
The second row:

[A –>relation2->Y->relation 1–>B   is a sample from path length 2
 the third row:

[A –>relation2->D–>relation2->F->relation 1–>B].   is a sample from path length 3

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, we'll need to collect the paths according to their length, so we have a row and list per length, then shuffle the collected paths and take one.

```
...
CALL apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(A, B, '', 3) YIELD path
WITH length(path) as length, collect(path) as paths
WITH length, apoc.coll.shuffle(paths)[0] as randomPath
ORDER BY length ASC
RETURN randomPath
```